# Count occurrences of only positive number

Tags: awk, count

I am trying to count occurrence of positive one (1) but I also have negative one (-1) in lines that's why its giving me cumulative count.

For example:

Script:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{print "count", "lineNum"}{print gsub(/1/,"") "\t" NR}' input_file


1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  0   0
-1  0   0   -1  -1  -1  0   0
1   1   0   -1  -1  -1  0   0
0   1   1   -1  -1  -1  0   0
```

Counts:

```
6
4
5
5
```

I am able to find count for only negative 1 (-1) using this command:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{print "count", "lineNum"}{print gsub(/\-1/,"") "\t" NR}' input_file
```

count for negative one (-1)

```
3
4
3
3
```

But unable to find desired count of only positive ones (1)

Desired count:

```
3
0
2
2
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to escape `-` in a regexp (unless it's inside a bracket expression and not at the start or end of it and then some awks may let you escape it instead of putting it at the start or end where it belongs).

Comment: Do you only have `-1`, `1`, and `0` in the file? What would you expect with `-11`? `1a`? `a-1`?

Comment: @Waqas Khokhar, by seeing your profile could see you have NEVER selected any answer as correct answer, please do select an answer as correct answer out of all to close the thread completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print gsub(/(^|[^-])1/,"")}' file
3
0
2
2
```

Comment: This will fail with input like `1 11 12 0` if 'fail' means counting three `1`'s there vs only 1 standalone '1'. Granted, the post was not clear if that is desired.

Comment: Given the sample input and the script that the OP says does work for `-1`s I think it's safe to assume that the input is 1, 0, and -1 exactly as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk, you can use word break assertions to definitively find `-1` vs `-11` (if those entries are possible.) Then use `gsub` to get the count of the positive `1` remaining in the line:

```
echo "1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  0   0
-1  0   0   -1  -1  -1  0   0
1   1   0   -1  -1  -1  0   0
0   1   1   -1  -1  -1  0   0" >file

$ gawk '{gsub(/-1\>/,""); print gsub(/\<1\>/,"1")}' file 
3
0
2
2
```

With POSIX awk, you can just loop the fields and check the values. Count them if it is what you seek:

```
$ awk '{cnt=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i+0==1) cnt++; print cnt}' file
3
0
2
2
```